Constrained balanced sums of roots of unity (Constrained centrifuge problem)
The centrifuge problem:  A centrifuge consists of a circular array of $n$ equally spaced slots, and $k$ objects of varying weights are placed in these slots. The goal is to arrange these weights such that the resulting system is balanced (has zero centroid)
Solutions: A nice overview of this problem as well as some results are given in papers by Matt Baker, see here and here, referencing earlier work on sums of the $n$th roots of unity by Lam and Leung and Sivek.
Extensions: I would like to find balanced configurations subject to additional constraints.
For example,

Reflection symmetry.  Equivalent to saying that for a $n$-slot centrifuge, if the $k$th slot is filled, then so is the $(n+1-k)$th slot.
Half masses. Specifically, balanced configurations where ONE of the filled slots has half mass.  A solution for $n=24$ would be $z^0+z^{18}+z^{8}+(1/2)z^{11} = 0$, where $z^1=\exp(\mathrm{2\pi i/24})\,$.

While one could brute force these solutions, is there some algorithm that could be used, based on further theorems about sums of roots of units?

There's also the paper of Conway and Jones in Acta Arithmetica.

Can you provide the citation?

I've given you the authors and the journal. How hard is it for you to find the bibliographic details?
